# How do you turn off test coverage reports in PHPStorm 9?

Tags: phpstorm, code-coverage

It seems once you've run tests with code coverage, there is no way to stop future test runs from displaying the code coverage in-line.

Even if I run tests normally (without coverage), the coverage remains.

If I select "Hide Coverage Data" from the tools menu, it just hides the coverage results menu.

How do I get it stop displaying in-line coverage in my source files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean that the coverage from a previous 'with code coverage' test remains, then yes, it remains until you manually clear it.

You can do so by using the view code coverage menu (alt + cmd + F6 on Mac, alt + ctrl + F6 on Win). Choose 'No code coverage' to remove all line highlighting.
You should also be able to select and re-enable previously generated code coverage results.)

Comment: Confirming that: once you cleared/hide coverage data and use "Run" .. it does not show coverage data from previous session where "Run with Coverage" was used. Just tested this in PhpStorm 9.0.2